# Why has my div changed when i add tags

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains other divs inside. I have set the css so they are arranged properly as shown here: [image: divs]

which i use the following code for:

**HTML**

```
<div class="catogories">

<div class="category"><img src="images/road-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>Road Bikes</h1></div>

<div class="category"><img src="images/mountain-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>Mountain Bikes</h1></div>

<div class="category"><img src="images/hybrid-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>Hybrid Bikes</h1></div>

<div class="category"><img src="images/city-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>City Bikes</h1></div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.catogories {
position: absolute;
width: 60%;
float: left;
left: 20%;
height: 600px;
top: 70%;
background-color: green;

}

.category {
position: relative;
height: 330px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
left: 5%;
margin: 4%;
background-color: red;
} 

.category h1{
font-size: 40px;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: center;
}
```

It all looks fine, so i decided to add links to them, make them clickable. So i added the < a > tag which completly ruined everything and i have no idea why. I even have a screenshot: 
[image: mixedup]

**HTML**

```
<div class="catogories">

<a href="#"><div class="category"><img src="images/road-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>Road Bikes</h1></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="category"><img src="images/mountain-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>Mountain Bikes</h1></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="category"><img src="images/hybrid-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>Hybrid Bikes</h1></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="category"><img src="images/city-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;">
    <h1>City Bikes</h1></div></a>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.catogories {
position: absolute;
width: 60%;
float: left;
left: 20%;
height: 600px;
top: 70%;
background-color: green;

}

.category {
position: relative;
height: 330px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
left: 5%;
margin: 4%;
background-color: red;
} 

.category h1{
font-size: 40px;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but just made it worse  https://gyazo.com/ff4349aa60c2a1b9c70d9933e4035033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to order them like this:

```
<div class="category">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/road-bikes.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;"><h1>Road Bikes</h1></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its works fine but the text isnt centered i cant move the h1 at all. https://gyazo.com/b4ccd7845fc333034dbe5115fdd87733

Comment: Did you tried to customize the h1 label from the css file ? or "align=center" inside h1 label ?

Comment: i customized it from the css file

Comment: The thing is i wanted the whole div to be click able, However with your help i am half way since only the image is clickable and not the whole div with the img and the text

Comment: Glad to help =)

Try to put all inside a table then.

Comment: wait, how do you put it inside a table

Comment: Like this :


<div class="category">
                <a href=""><table>
                               <td>
                               <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 300px; height:200px;"><h1>bikes</h1></a>
                               </td>
                </table></a>
</div>